# How to convert the datatype of a column from String to List in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

In my Panda's dataframe I have a set of columns with datatype string, and I want to typecast them into the list.

For example - I want to convert the string "`['C0020649', 'C0020538', 'C0020649']`" into a list `['C0020649', 'C0020538', 'C0020649']` so that I can iterate through each element.

Initially, I tried to typecast using `ast.literal_eval()` but it throws ValueError:

```
malformed node or string: 14 error.
```

The most interesting thing here is that the datatype of the column is automatically converted into string type whenever I try to save the values in the dataframe's column as a list.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to replace the column or add another column with list versions of each cells, here's a somewhat clumsy, but non-eval() solution I came up with:

```
def str_to_list(cell):
    cell = ''.join(c for c in cell if c not in "'[]")
    cell = cell.split(', ')
    return cell

df = pd.DataFrame({'Column 1': ["['C0020649', 'C0020538', 'C0020649']",
                                "['C0050245', 'C0010689', 'C0042623']",
                                "['C0045734', 'C0025325', 'C0023542']"]})

df['Column 1'] = df['Column 1'].apply(str_to_list)
```

Or if you prefer using lambda:

```
df['Column 1'] = df['Column 1'].apply(lambda cell:
                                      ''.join(c for c in cell if c not in "'[]").split(', '))
```

Edit: This will probably break if you are using `"'"` `"["` `"]"` or `", "` inside your strings, but it looks like you won't be, so it's ok.

Comment: Thank you very much. Given the items of my list, the str_to_list( ) works fine for me. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

First, the `dtype` for these columns (Series) is `object`.  It can contain strings, lists, number etc.  Usually they all look the same because pandas omits any quotes.  pandas does not use the `numpy` string dtypes.

`df[col].to_numpy()` seems to be a good way of seeing what the actual Series elements are.

If the column contains lists, the `tocsv()` writes  the `str(alist)` version of the list (or other objects).  The csv reader loads those as strings; it does not try to parse them.  Look at the `csv`, and again check the the Series `to_numpy()`.

A Series containing lists:

```
In [377]: s = pd.Series([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])                                                           
In [378]: s                                                                                          
Out[378]: 
0    [1, 2, 3]
1    [4, 5, 6]
dtype: object
In [379]: s.to_numpy()                                                                               
Out[379]: array([list([1, 2, 3]), list([4, 5, 6])], dtype=object)
```

Writing to file:

```
In [380]: s.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)                                                          
In [381]: cat test.csv                                                                               
0
"[1, 2, 3]"
"[4, 5, 6]"
```

reading from the file:

```
In [382]: df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')                                                               
In [383]: df                                                                                         
Out[383]: 
           0
0  [1, 2, 3]
1  [4, 5, 6]
In [384]: df.to_numpy()                                                                              
Out[384]: 
array([['[1, 2, 3]'],
       ['[4, 5, 6]']], dtype=object)
```

Note the change to strings.

`applying` `eval` to each column string:

```
In [389]: df1 = df['0'].apply(eval)                                                                  
In [390]: df1                                                                                        
Out[390]: 
0    [1, 2, 3]
1    [4, 5, 6]
Name: 0, dtype: object
In [391]: df1.to_numpy()                                                                             
Out[391]: array([list([1, 2, 3]), list([4, 5, 6])], dtype=object)
```

There may be something better, but that's at least a start.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. I mean to say the column elements are getting converted to string type when I am trying to save them as lists. So type(df.colname[0]) = string and I am required to iterate through df.colname[i] list.

Comment: Applying eval works and can be a temporary solution but I want to figure out why upon reading the csv, lists are converted into strings. It sure becomes an overhead for processing large files

Comment: I showed you.  The lists are written as strings - see the quotes?  `csv` is 2d format - rows and columns.  Your lists add a 3rd dimension, which can only be fudged.  You aren't the first to run into this problem.  It's worse if you have `ndarray` in the cells.  The `str()` of an array cannot be `eval`.

Comment: Your lists violate, to some degree, the essential 2d character of a DataFrame - rows and columns - and with some thing else in each cell.  It only works by using this object dtype.  Looking at previous SO like this, I see either this `apply` solution, or suggestions to use a different save format.